# consume soap service with ruby and savon

Tags: ruby, soap, wsdl, savon

I'm trying to use ruby and Savon to consume a web service.

The test service is http://www.webservicex.net/WS/WSDetails.aspx?WSID=9&CATID=2

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'savon'

client = Savon::Client.new "http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL"
client.get_quote do |soap| 
  soap.body = {:symbol => "AAPL"} 
end
```

Which returns an SOAP exception. Inspecting the soap envelope, it looks to me that the soap request doesn't have the correct namespace(s).

Can anyone suggest what I can do to make this work?
I have the same problem with other web service endpoints as well.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a problem with the way Savon handles Namespaces. See this answer [Why is "wsdl" namespace interjected into action name when using savon for ruby soap communication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294325/why-is-wsdl-namespace-interjected-into-action-name-when-using-savon-for-ruby-so)

You can resolve this by specifically calling soap.input and passing it an array, the first element is the method and the second is a hash containing the namespace(s)

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'savon'

client = Savon::Client.new "http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL"
client.get_quote do |soap| 
  soap.input = [ 
    "GetQuote", 
    { "xmlns" => "http://www.webserviceX.NET/" } 
  ]
  soap.body = {:symbol => "AAPL"} 
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You might find the latest gem uses the method "request" followed by the symbol reference to the method required.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'savon'

client = Savon::Client.new "http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL"
client.request :get_quote do |soap| 
    soap.input = [ 
    "GetQuote", 
    { "xmlns" => "http://www.webserviceX.NET/" } 
    ]
    soap.body = {:symbol => "AAPL"} 
end
```